# Inner product on forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I have the following form
$$\omega = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_3 \wedge dx_4$$

and I want to compute the interior product : $g^*(\omega,\omega)$ (I think $g^*$ is not standard notation but it is just to indicate the interior product on forms).

I have the first step of the  solution:
$$g^*(\omega,\omega) = g^*(dx_1 \wedge dx_2, dx_1 \wedge dx_2) + 2g^*(dx_1 \wedge dx_2, dx_3 \wedge dx_4) + g^*(dx_3 \wedge dx_4, dx_3 \wedge dx_4)$$

But I don't really understand how to get it. Can someone help me ?

Comment: This is just using the bilinearity of $g$.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you !

Comment: You are welcome! I just add that it also uses the symmetry of $g$ (or $g^*$).